# React Native Branch - Handling no network and avoiding error

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-ios, branch.io

So in the case that there's no network connection available with calling it seems to be that with

```
  this._unsubscribeFromBranch = branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error from Branch: " + error)
      return
    }
```

Would result in an error saying `branch could not reach the server` or so, what's the best way to handle this, please?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: If there is a network issue, and Branch initialization returns the error, you should make sure that your application runs smoothly. For example, if you have initialized Branch and you have routing logic based on the link parameters, you should add the routing logic in the error section as well.

Comment: PS: The Branch SDK has a retry logic in place, which resends the request to the API. By default, the retry count is set to 3 in the Android SDK. If you wish to change the retry count you can use the native SDK method (Reference documentation [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/blob/c6ce21f06a72b1819ccc600d5cded4ee581cbd5b/Branch-SDK/src/io/branch/referral/PrefHelper.java#L211) )

Comment: Thanks, yes it just seems that an error would occur immediately if branch.subscribe wasn't successful say if you have no internet connection for example. You can wrap around using NetInfo to check if its active if an network connection is required ... I assume it would be using branch links.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue you are describing. Could you provide more information.